# felt or feeling in this case

Tags: progressive-aspect

> It brings back memories of one summer evening several years ago. We had spent the day on the beach and we were walking back to the apartment. It must have been 10 o'clock and it **still felt** warm.

Why is it not" it was still feeling " is it because it was a habit (in Spain where the story happened), at 10 o'clock you still feel warm or is it because still implies a continuous action

Comment: The continuous verb form in *we were walking back* strongly implies that there's ***more text following*** (not provided here) telling us more about what else was going on during that process of walking back. Note that syntactically speaking there's absolutely nothing wrong with using the continuous *...and it **was still feeling** warm* here - it's just that *stylistically*, most writers would consider that one use of the continuous is enough to establish the relevant temporal context. Repeatedly using more complex verb forms generally leads to clumsy/awkward text, is all.

Comment: The verb *to feel* is usually stative, especially when copular.  We're much more likely to use "it was warm" or "it felt warm" than "it was being warm" or "it was feeling warm".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you use the verb **feel** in a simple form, the subject can be a person who feels something, or something that a person can feel a property of.

> I feel cold - *subject is a person*
> The stove feels cold - *subject is what a person can feel a property of*

When you use it in a continuous form, the subject can only be a person, not a thing:

> I am feeling cold - *correct*
> The stove is feeling cold. - *incorrect*

In your sentence, **feel** relates to the weather: you have to use a simple form **still felt**. You cannot use the continuous form **was still feeling** because the weather is not a person.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20felt%20warm%2C%20it%20was%20feeling%20warm&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20felt%20warm%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cit%20felt%20warm%3B%2Cc0) supports this idea: there are many occurrences of **it felt warm** and none whatsoever of **it was feeling warm**.